# How to type a function with Callable without losing keyword argument?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have many functions and I want to add a stringify option on each function: if `stringify=True`, the functions returns `str(result)` instead of `result`.

Instead of adding the optional argument and refactoring each function (which would force me to duplicate the stringify logic across all my functions) I used a decorator:

```
from typing import Callable, Union


def WithStringifyOption(func: Callable[[int], int]) -> Callable[[int, bool], Union[int, str]]:
    def wrapper(value: int, stringify: bool = False) -> Union[int, str]:
        result = func(value)
        return str(result) if stringify else result
    return wrapper

# my old function
def func0(value: int) -> int:
    return value * 2

# How it looks now
@WithStringifyOption
def func1(value: int) -> int:
    return value * 2


func0(value=2)
func1(value=3, stringify=True)
```

The code works, but by doing this, I get typing error (and I lose autocomplete for keyword arguments): `Unexpected keyword argument "value" for "func1"mypy(error)` and `Unexpected keyword argument "stringify" for "func1"mypy(error)`

According to typing documentation about [`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable):

> There is no syntax to indicate optional or keyword arguments; such function types are rarely used as callback types.

**So how can I fix this typing error ?**

*Note: this is a simplified example on my real project; i want to add a much more complex logic on each one of my functions, so refactoring all my functions by adding and duplicating this complex logic is not an option. I also don't want to add `type: ignore` everywhere on the project and i don't want to replace all keyword arguments by positional arguments everywhere on the project*

Comment: [Please avoid posting pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, post the text itself. BTW, the screenshot says `stringify_option`, but the code above says `func1`.

Comment: BTW, where is that `(function)` message coming from? I don't have that in my VSCode. Are you using Pylance? I'm using Jedi.

Comment: @wjandrea Yes I did a mistake on the screen shot (I renamed the function on the code and forgot to change the screenshot, it should be func0). I did not know I should avoid putting screenshot, I understand why now, thank you.

Comment: Yes I work on VScode with Pylance, I'm not sure what generates the first line (probably pylance), it's the first line is not an error it just indicates the type of what i am hovering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Protocol`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html)s:

```
from typing import Protocol
# if sys.version_info < (3, 8): from typing_extensions import Protocol


class CallableIn(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, value: int) -> int: ...


class CallableOut(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, value: int, stringify: bool = False) -> int | str: ...


def WithStringifyOption(func: CallableIn) -> CallableOut:
    def wrapper(value: int, stringify: bool = False) -> int | str:
        result = func(value)
        return str(result) if stringify else result
    return wrapper
```

Try out [your snippet in mypy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=afb2d0db29c8176e5076cbbcbfaea4d3) to check.