# How to execute async request with up to K workers without code duplication?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have a project with many async functions (they do http call to a remote server).
The server can handle up to k simultaneous request (it depends of which request i do)
I want to be able to easily implement **"do this N requests with up to K workers"**. I could not find a way without either duplicating code or loosing type hints.
**How to do it ?**

I tried to use Semaphore but failed to use it, mainly because I could not find a way to move this logic at the caller scope.

### implement logic on caller scope (not working)

```
import asyncio
import time


async def sleep(s: int):
    await asyncio.sleep(s)
    print(f'task done in {s}s')
    return s

sem = asyncio.Semaphore(2)

# Expect to ends in 8 seconds, ends in 6 (not the correct behavior)
start = time.time()
async with sem:
  res = await asyncio.gather(*[
    sleep(6), 
    sleep(2), 
    sleep(2), 
    sleep(2), 
    sleep(2), 
    sleep(2), 
  ])
end = time.time()
print(f"ended in {end-start}s")
```

### Refactoring async functions (code duplication)

```
import asyncio
import time
from typing import Optional

async def sleep(s: int):
    await asyncio.sleep(s)

async def request_0(arg0: int, sem: Optional[asyncio.Semaphore]=None):
  if sem is not None:
    async with sem:
      await sleep(2) # Do http call 0
  else:
    await sleep(2) # Do http call 0

async def request_1(arg1: str, sem: Optional[asyncio.Semaphore]=None):
  if sem is not None:
    async with sem:
      await sleep(1) # Do http call 1
  else:
    await sleep(1) # Do http call 1

async def request_2(arg2: float, arg3: str, sem: Optional[asyncio.Semaphore]=None):
  if sem is not None:
    async with sem:
      await sleep(1) # Do http call 2
  else:
    await sleep(1) # Do http call 2


start = time.time()
async with asyncio.Semaphore(2) as sem:
  res = await asyncio.gather(*[
    request_0(arg0=0),
    request_1(arg1='0'),
    request_2(arg2=0, arg3='0'),
  ])
end = time.time()
print(f"ended in {end-start}s")
```

### Enhance functions with annotation (losing type hints)

```
# type: ignore
import asyncio
import time
from typing import Callable, Coroutine, Optional, Any


async def sleep(s: int):
    await asyncio.sleep(s)


def semaphoreUseable(func):
    async def wrapper(*args, sem=Optional[asyncio.Semaphore], **kwargs):
        if sem is not None:
            async with sem:
                return await func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return await func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@semaphoreUseable
async def request_0(arg0: int):
    await sleep(2)  # http call 0


@semaphoreUseable
async def request_1(arg1: str):
    await sleep(1)  # http call 1


@semaphoreUseable
async def request_2(arg2: float, arg3: str):
    await sleep(1)  # http call 2


async def main():
    start = time.time()
    async with asyncio.Semaphore(2) as sem:
        res = await asyncio.gather(*[
            request_0(arg0=0, sem=sem),
            request_1(arg1='0', sem=sem),
            request_2(arg2=0, arg3='0', sem=sem),
        ])
    end = time.time()
    print(f"ended in {end-start}s")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

*related question: [How to type a function with Callable without losing keyword argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73449645/212858) (could not find a way to type the annotation solution)*

Comment: Why does each request need a separate function? It seems this would be easier if you had a single function. Context like this can be hard to gather from toy examples.

Comment: @dirn For instance, i have a function that takes an range (a tuple of int) and do get request that returns a object of type A and handle the case of missing data in the response, I have another function that takes a string and returns an object of type B, another one takes a list of string and do a post request, and so on...

Comment: ```time.sleep(1)``` is blocking, not a natural way to go with asyncio. If you can, a solution that works more like ```await asyncio.sleep(1)``` is better.

Comment: @jwal I already use `await asyncio.sleep(1)` (i import time to measure time not to sleep)